# .net coding through Copy all the data from one excel workbook to another

Tags: c#, .net

Please help me..
How to Copy all the data (only data not structure) from one excel workbook to another excel workbook using C#.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is tabular you might be able to use OLEDB to do it just treating the Excel workbooks as datasources. This Code Project article should show you how to get started: [Reading and Writing Excel using OLEDB](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx)

If you can't use OLEDB then you can do it via Excel Automation. This article shows you how to get started with that: [How to transfer data to an Excel workbook by using Visual C# 2005 or Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306023)